# Strapi Forgot password API customization

Tags: api, unique, strapi, forgot-password

I am using strapi V4. I want to customize forgot password API. When the user hits API then strapi is sending the email to the user's email address with a unique code. Instead of that code, I want only 4 digit unique number. How can I do this please help me.